# Get only posts with has latest one comment, which has more then 5 reputation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I has $posts collection instance and i wont to get only that posts which has comments and latest one comments has more 5 reputation. My collection instance similar this

```
[
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Some title',
        'comments' => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'content' => 'some content',
                'reputation' => 5
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'content' => 'some content',
                'reputation' => 6
            ],
            ...
        ],
    ],
    ...
]
```

My code is

```
$posts = $posts->filter(function ($post, $key) {
    $isHasMoreFiveComments = false;
    foreach ($post['comments'] as $comment) {
        if ($comment['reputation'] > 5) {
            $isHasMoreFiveComments = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $isHasMoreFiveComments;
});
```

but i think there is more good solution.

Comment: why downvote ?. What is bad??

Comment: Probably, they saw that it's not clear when you first post your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find more good solution here code

```
$posts = $posts->filter(function ($post, $key) {
    $comments = collect($post['comments']);
    return $comments->pluck('reputation')->max() > 5;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what are you trying to get here but probably this will work for you?

bellow will retrieve posts that has at least 1 comment with reputations 5 and above also it's in descending order.

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('comments')->with(['comments'=>function($q){
    $q->where('reputation', '>', 4); 
    $q->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}])->get();
```

Note: you have to initialized the relationship of `commments` in you `Post` model

ex:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But I need to get all posts and after it filter only my conditions posts

Comment: Okay, probably you can post your filter also.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to comments that has reputation more than 5, then [@Jesus Erwin Suarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4551227/jesus-erwin-suarez)'s answer is correct.

But if you wanted to get another field to check whether the post has comments with reputation more than 5 or not, this will work:

```
// this will add an extra column `has_reputed_comments` in rows
$posts = Post::selectRaw('*, IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM comments where comments.post_id = posts.id AND comments.reputation > 5 ORDER BY id DESC), 1, 0) as has_reputed_comments')->get();
```

**UPDATED**

To filter a collection as mentioned in comment, you can do this:

```
// this will return filtered result by reputation greater than 5
$comments = $posts->comments->where('reputation', '>', 5);
```

Comment: It's always a bad practice to fetch everything at once, however I'll update my answer.